# getting tzinfo from a column rather than a single string

Tags: python, pandas

Usually you can localize a whole column with tz_localize.  If you specify the single value timezone you want the column localized to formatted.  How would you do this when there is a column of timezones?

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.tz_localize.html#pandas.Series.dt.tz_localize

```
     start_datetime       timezone
1   2016-08-25 10:30:00  US/Pacific
2   2006-08-26 14:00:00  US/Pacific
3   2016-08-27 10:15:00  US/Eastern
4   2016-08-28 10:30:00  US/Central
5   2016-08-09 17:45:00  US/Central
```

Is there a way to do this without lambdas or apply? (best option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can group by `timezone` and apply `.dt.tz_localize(group_timezone)` to each group:

```
In [393]: df['new'] = \
              df.groupby('timezone')['start_datetime'] \
                .transform(lambda x: x.dt.tz_localize(x.name))

In [394]: df
Out[394]:
       start_datetime    timezone                 new
0 2016-08-25 10:30:00  US/Pacific 2016-08-25 17:30:00
1 2006-08-26 14:00:00  US/Pacific 2006-08-26 21:00:00
2 2016-08-27 10:15:00  US/Eastern 2016-08-27 14:15:00
3 2016-08-28 10:30:00  US/Central 2016-08-28 15:30:00
4 2016-08-09 17:45:00  US/Central 2016-08-09 22:45:00
```